# How can set collate en_us.UTF-8 in order by query on Sequelize

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

On postgres, order by with collate and lower writing like below.

```
ORDER BY convert_to(lower(column COLLATE "en_US"), 'UTF8')
```

But in sequelize, where should I put the "collate" query and how I write it.

```
// This is omitted "collate" query
sequelize.fn('convert_to', sequelize.fn('lower', sequelize.col(column)), '\'UTF8\''), 'ASC')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing the argument to `lower()` as a `sequelize.literal()` You also do not need to include the single quotes in "UTF8", just passing the string will do.

```js
order: [
  sequelize.fn(
    'convert_to', 
    sequelize.fn(
      'lower', 
      sequelize.literal('column COLLATE "en_US"')
    ), 
    'UTF8'), 
  'ASC')
]
```